# Change state "Use GPS satellites" in Setting From My Application

Tags: android, gps, location

I have Toggle to change state Use GPS satellites in setting check/uncheck.
When I check in my app, but don't know to change state in setting. Help me to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change GPS setting anymore after ICS.
To do that, you have to modify Settings.Secure, but only manufacturer could change those values.